# Why is mongoose find method not async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async-await

**Old code with promises**

I have some old code using mongoose. It fetches some information from the database. `AccountViewPermission` is a schema. All good. I am accessing it with a `.then` which makes it behave like a Promise.

```
AccountViewPermission.find({ requested_by: request.body.credentials.character.id})
.then( permissions => {
  response.status(200).json(permissions)
})
```

**Documentation mentions await capability**

According to [the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) I should also be able to use asyn/await:

> Mongoose queries are not promises. They have a .then() function for co and async/await as a convenience. However, unlike promises, calling a query's .then() can execute the query multiple times.

**But using await throws an error**

So I started writing this code with an `await` instead of a (wannabe) promise.

```
const permissions = await AccountViewPermission.find({ requested_by: request.body.credentials.character.id})
response.status(200).json(permissions)
```

However now node.js throws me an error: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. Which is true, but the docs say mongoose should still be able to use `await`.

**How can I use the await syntax in this scenario?**

Comment: Well you get the answer in the error message. You have to wrap your logic inside an async function. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the official docs `"The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used inside an async function."` Docs: [await-operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Mongoose cant change the way javascript deals with async / await keywords. if you need follow-up information check the docs.

To make your code work you HAVE to wrap it inside a async function. There is no way around this.

```js
async function doSomething() {
  const permissions = await AccountViewPermission.find({
    requested_by: request.body.credentials.character.id
  })
  response.status(200).json(permissions)
}
```

Comment: My wrong understanding was that the `find` method being called was supposed to be `async`. But the await has to be inside a async marked function. Maybe this insight is a gotcha for others too, hence this comment.